# Access Wordpress WP-Admin through /admin URL

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I want to access to my `/wp-admin` through a different URL, such as `/admin`.

If I do `localhost:5000/admin` I got redirected to `localhost:8000/wp-admin`, the requirement is that I should see the Wordpress administration panel at that exact URL.

I'm using `docker-compose` and `nginx`.

My `nginx.conf` file looks like:

```
events { worker_connections 1024; }
http{
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name localhost;

    location ~* /admin {
        rewrite ^/admin/(.*) /wp-admin last;
        proxy_pass http://wordpress;
        proxy_set_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;


    }
  }

}
```

And my docker-compose.yml file is:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.6
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./backend/db/db_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./backend/db/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    environment: 
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: p4ssw0rd!
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress

  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8081:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: p4ssw0rd!



  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - phpmyadmin
      - db
    image: wordpress
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./backend/wordpress/wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
      - ./backend/wordpress/.htaccess:/var/www/html/.htaccess
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: p4ssw0rd!
      WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: ab_
      WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA:
        define('JWT_AUTH_SECRET_KEY', 'secret');
        define('JWT_AUTH_CORS_ENABLE', true);
        define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true );
    ports:
      - 8000:80 # Expose http and https
      - 8001:443

  nginx:
    build: ./backend/nginx
    volumes:
      - ./backend/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
    links: 
      - wordpress
      - frontend
    depends_on: 
      - wordpress
      - frontend
```

Not an `nginx` expert so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try: `rewrite ^/admin(/.*)?$ /wp-admin$1 break;`

Comment: If I do that I got redirected to `http://localhost/wp-admin/`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this filter too

```
function custom_admin_url($path) { 
    return str_replace('wp-admin', 'admin', $path); 
}
add_filter('admin_url', 'custom_admin_url');
```

Comment: Add it in functions.php file in your theme

Comment: I don't have themes as I'm using Wordpress as a headless CMS, is it possible to put it somewhere else?

Comment: In that case try adding it as a plugin, a must use plugin that will always be activated.
In wp-content/mu-plugins create new php file and add the code there. If mu-plugins doesn't exists create the directory. Wordpress will execute that file automatically.